# Is there a ruby library (or builtin) for representing file permissions in symbolic notation?

Tags: ruby, permissions

`File::Stat#mode` returns file permissions as a decimal number (*e.g.,* 16832). Performing `to_s(8)` gives the corresponding octal representation (40700).

Is there any builtin method or library for outputting permissions in symbolic notation (“drwx------”), the way they're formatted in `ls -l`?

Comment: The format of `ls -l` is platform dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's pretty easy to do it yourself. Just create a mapping between numeric and string representation, then convert it:

```
permissions_map = {
  '7' => 'rwx',
  '6' => 'rw-',
  '5' => 'r-x',
  '4' => 'r--',
  '3' => '-wx',
  '2' => '-w-',
  '1' => '--x'
}

Dir.foreach('./') do |item|
  next if ['.', '..'].include?(item)
  f = File.stat(item)
  permission_string = ''
  sprintf('%o', f.mode)[-3..-1].chars.each do |digit|
    permission_string << permissions_map[digit]
  end
  puts permission_string
end
```